# Clear/transparent header with background and scrollable ion-content?

Tags: css, mobile, ionic-framework, sass

This may be a long one. I am currently building an Ionic application and I decided to try for clear headers. This is the look that I am trying to achieve across the app: [image: Successful clear]

It looks good, and I managed to get it working. The problem is, since the header is on top of the `ion-content` that has the background, when I scroll `ion-content` this happens: [image: Scrolled under header]

The scrolled content that should be out of view is visible under the transparent header. Is there a way to make it look like it goes under the header, but without it being visible? Like it would look if the header were a solid color instead.

One of my options is getting a similar background on the header and style it so that it *looks* somewhat transparent, but ultimately it would be noticeable that they are different images.

The header and background have the following rules:

```
.clear-header{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.10) !important;
    h1{color: $light;};
    .title{ color: $light};
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}

.blur-background { 
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url([url of image]);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: use position relative or absolute according to your need and use z-index a slightly greater value then others. (say 99999). lets see if it works

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean with using relative or absolute position according to my needs? Also, I tried changing the z-index of the header but it changed nothing.